# Requesting different endpoints with firestore Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to have a flexible Cloud Function that executes on different end points.

My original Cloud Function looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const _ = require('lodash')
const { getObjectValues } = require('./helper-functions.js')
admin.initializeApp()

const json2csv = require('json2csv').parse
exports.csvJsonReport = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const db = admin.firestore()
  const userAnswers = db.collection('/surveys/CNA/submissions')
  return (
    userAnswers
      .get()
      // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        let surveySubmissions = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const userSubmission = doc.data()
          surveySubmissions.push({
            ..._.mapValues(userSubmission.answers, getObjectValues), // format answers
            ...userSubmission.anonUser,
          })
        })

        const csv = json2csv(surveySubmissions)
        response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=cna.csv')
        response.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
        response.status(200).send(csv)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  )
})
```

I am trying to extend this function to work on multiple collections. In the above function I am targeting the `CNA` collection. so instead of `db.collection('/surveys/CNA/submissions/')` I would like it to be `db.collection('/surveys/:surveyId/submissions/')`

Below is my attempt at trying to extend my original Cloud Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const _ = require('lodash')
const { getObjectValues } = require('./helper-functions.js')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const db = admin.firestore()

const app = express()
const main = express()

main.use('/api/v1', app)
main.use(bodyParser.json())

exports.webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main)

app.get('surveys/:id', (request, response) => {
  const surveyId = request.query
  const userAnswers = db.collection(`/survey/${surveyId}/submissions`)
  return (
    userAnswers
      .get()
      // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        let surveySubmissions = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const userSubmission = doc.data()
          surveySubmissions.push({
            ..._.mapValues(userSubmission.answers, getObjectValues), // format answers
            ...userSubmission.anonUser,
          })
        })

        const csv = json2csv(surveySubmissions)
        response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=cna.csv')
        response.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
        response.status(200).send(csv)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  )
})
```

When I request my endpoint: `myapp.firebaseapp.com/api/v1/surveys/CNA`
`Cannot GET /api/v1/surveys/CNA` is shown in my browser.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To crate a GET /survey/:id endpoint in order to fetch a submission by id, use the following code in your new Cloud Function:

```
app.get('surveys/:id', (request, response) => {
  const surveyId = request.params.id
  const userAnswers = db.collection(`/survey/${surveyId}/submissions`)
```

Let me know if it works for you.